# Ionic 4 & Firebase (FCM) - How to group push notifications

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I'm using Firebase as my backend for my app (Ionic v4). On certain events, I notify the desired clients via Firebase Cloud Messaging. The problem is, it starts to get messy when there are lots of event occurring. I don't want to bombard the clients' devices. Therefore, I was looking for a way to "group" them to a single push notification (just like WhatsApp does).

I've heard about channels but looks like it's supported only on Android O and above. Plus, My device runs Android 7 and looks like WhatsApp can still group their messages, so I believe it's possible to achieve without channels.

I've heard about the `tag` property too. The problem with this property is that it's overriding the current notification with the same tag, instead of grouping the notifications.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to send push notification to the group of topic, add this lines inside the platform ready.

`this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('people');`